# Implementing backspace using outtextxy in graphics.h in c

Tags: c, bgi

I was trying to create a text editor in c. but i am facing a problem with the backspace character. and when i am trying to print this with outtextxy a strange character is appearing.
i tried following code for this backspace:

**str[2]="\b ";**

**outtextxy(x,y,str);**

This is working fine under textmode but not working under graphics mode.

Answer (score 1):

That's been a good 20 years since I last laid eyes on that.  It is a low-level graphics output function in BGI (IIRC).  You'll get the glyph for code 8, a rectangle with a circle in the OEM character set.

To make it act like, say, puts(), you'll have to interpret the control codes yourself.  If you see a backspace (char 8), you'll have to update your internal "cursor position" variable and move x back by the font width.  Same for '\n' (increment y) and '\r' (set x to 0).

Answer (score 0):

Since U are in Graphics mode:

1. **[STEP 1]** Keep track of current position using two **ints** (say x,y)
2. **[STEP 2]** Whenever backspace is pressed:

   1st Check if  x==0,y==0 : Emit a beep;

   Else check if x==0, y>0 : Then make x= screen-width, y=y-1;

   Else check if  x>0, y>0 : Then x=x-1;

Now That U hav the right x,y co-ordinates, just **outtextxy** a NULL/space character at the position.

**NOTE:** After **outtextxy** do NOT increment x as the cursor is still supposed to be at the prev character position.

GOOD LUCK!!